# deleting columns from a .csv file using information from another .csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I have two csv files. File one  (consumption.scv) has the household identifier number in the header and hourly consumption values in each row. Each column represents another hosuehold. File two is one column with only household numbers which I would like to include.
I would like to produce a file which only includes the consumption time series of households which are included in file b.

consumption<-read.csv
householdno<-read.csv

I am stuck with the following: 
consumption_new<-consumption[,c(xxxxxx)]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please show few lines of reproducible example and expected output based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't included [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3552063), I had to create one:

```
set.seed(123)
consumption <- matrix(floor(runif(26*3, 10, 30)), nrow=3)
colnames(consumption) <- LETTERS
householdno <- data.frame(houses=sample(LETTERS, 5))
```

```
consumption[, colnames(consumption) %in% householdno[,1]]
#       C  F  J  P  Z
# [1,] 20 27 21 12 14
# [2,] 27 14 15 14 17
# [3,] 21 10 12 19 22
```

The trick is to use [**logical vector** to subset columns from data.frame](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). TRUE includes column, FALSE excludes it.

[`%in%`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) will check whether every element in **first** vector exists in **second** vector. It returns logical vector of length of first vector.

Finishing touch is to use that logical vector to subset desire columns from data.frame. This would be more readable if you decided to store that vector in variable.

Comment: Hi @maaar, if my answer helped you to solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312562).